# Weird array glitch

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, jbutton

I was making a ludo game(for a CPU and a human player) with java swing, using a Jframe. There are a total of 70 movement buttons, I was trying to make three arrays, two for holding the token positions of the two players and the third for holding all the buttons but there seems to be a problem.

```
private static javax.swing.JButton B1;
private static javax.swing.JButton B10;
private static javax.swing.JButton B11;
```

and so on...

```
static JButton[] allButtons = {B9, B10, B11, B12, B13, B14, B15, B16, B17, B18, B19, B20, B21, B22, B23, B24, B25, B26, B27,
          B28, B29, B30, B31, B32, B33, B34, B35, B36, B37, B38, B39, B40, B41, B42, B43, B44, B45, B46,
          B47, B48, B49, B50, B51, B52, B53, B54, B55, B56, B57, B58, B59, B60, B61, B62, B63, B64, B65,
          B66, B67, B68, B69, B70};
static JButton[] positionsA = {null, null, null, null};
static JButton[] positionsB = {B40, null, null, null};
```

Now, the problem is this statement is returning false

```
JButton moverB(){
System.out.println(allButtons[31]==positionsB[0]);
}
```

Both of the indexes refer to B40

Comment: What happens in between initialization and calling `moverB` ? does anything else modify either array?

Comment: The arrays aren't modified in any way.

Comment: Do you initialise the `B#` variables before you put the buttons into your arrays?

Comment: And what is the output of `System.out.println(allButtons[31]);` and `System.out.println(positionsB[0]);`?

Comment: Both the outputs are null.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Wait.. I thought in Java `null==null` resolves to `true`?

Comment: `System.out.println(allButtons[31]);
    System.out.println(positionsB[0]);
    System.out.println(B40);` first two return null, third one returns the button, I can't understand what's going on here.

Comment: @Avantol13 You are right. Not my day. I messed up Oracle database `null` concept with `Java`. See [Nulls in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm). Looks like my brain merged my knowledge of `Oracle` and `Java` over the years.

Answer (score 0):

As the all array starts with B9 at `[0]` and then counts up, `[31]` should be B40.

However B40 at the declarations of both arrays should already be initialized; and I seen no such thing:

```
private static javax.swing.JButton B40 = new JButton();
```

In fact this probably makes the array technique as above probably not so nice.

Better start immediately with an array. Also refrain from static if possible.
A bit like:

```
class X {

    private static X x; // Maybe one instance.

    private JButton[] buttons;

    public X() {
        buttons = new JButton[70];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
            JButton button = new JButton();
            ...
            buttons[i] = button;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X.x = new X();
    }
```

Then you have your arrays from the beginning.

Comment: The thing is that the Jframe automatically declares the Jbuttons this way, is there any way to override this?

Comment: That would be fine. Maybe it is a matter of static fields (once globally) versus non-st might static fields (of the JFrae object)? Maybe you first try this concept in a new protype application. Make one button and use that code to do an array of buttons.